# X11 forwarding MATLAB under Ubuntu 15.04 leads to issues with text visualization

Tags: ssh, 15.04, java, matlab

I am using ssh -Y to connect to a remote cluster from a laptop running Ubuntu 15.04, and when I launch MATLAB version 2013a or later, text is incorrectly displayed (e.g. in the editor, portions of scripts are missing). This issue is not present when connecting to the same cluster with another laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. The issue is also not present when using the laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 to connect to the cluster an launch MATLAB version 2010b. Possibly some changes in java support from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 that affect specifically some aspects of Swing that have been added to MATLAB in recent versions? Has anybody had experience with this and knows of any fixes (possibly other than replacing Ubuntu 15.04 with 14.04)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was a particular case of the following issue:
https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/08/08/random-disappearing-letters/
which in my case only affected MATLAB over ssh. Reverting from SNA to UXA fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I had the same issue running Ubuntu 16.04 and Matlab 2014 and 2015. I used the x2go client. Maybe one can add the two tags "16.04" and "x2go" so that more people can find this solution. Also don't forget to reboot.